# Queries in google drive api for searching files

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I can't understand how to set ImageMediaMetadata.Width in query. Google Drive Api guides didn't help me. I can't use an internal property using their example.

```
appProperties has { key='additionalID' and value='8e8aceg2af2ge72e78' }
```

Has anyone understood how to use the internal fields of variables?

```
FileList result = service.files().list()
                .setPageSize(20)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(*)")
                .setQ("trashed = false and imageMediaMetadata has { width < 1920 }")
                .execute();
```

Comment: I don't understand much your question, sorry. You want to know how to query your files using imageMediaMetadata?

Comment: I think i get it know, you want to query the files using custom file properties right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to use custom file property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you try to retrieve the **downloadUrl** attribute in `file.downloadUrl`, which is a field that doesn’t exist anymore in the Drive API version 3 (It was in the version 2), check v2 [1] and v3 [2].

Instead, you should use the **webContentLink** attribute to download the file, which is available for files with binary content as images, pdf, etc, but not for google docs and sheets (it’s only available the **webViewLink** attribute which is the url to the file) [2]. For these cases (docs and sheets), you can implement the **import** method which works for convert google documents and returns the file object [3].

The import request would be like this:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.import({ 'fileId': fileId, 'mimeType': mimeType });
```

With mimeType for the target document you want (pdf, txt, etc). Then, inside the callback, access the attribute using file.webContentLink as with the other cases.

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files

[2] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files

[3] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export